# Parse Server & Dashboard restarting on PM2 causing 502 Bad Gateway

Tags: nginx, parse-server, pm2

I have installed Parse Server and Parse Dashboard on an AWS EC2 instance (Ubuntu 14.04). I am using pm2 process manager to configure and run both applications and nginx to serve as a proxy server.

Both applications are working fine and I can access them from the client. The problem however is that when I access Parse Dashboard (which internally performs calls to local Parse Server) majority of the POST commands  are returned with 502 Bad Gateway error.

After some investigation I suspect pm2 is the problem as it keeps on restarting applications after some time since all the POST commands are executed at the same time. I set the max_memory_restart parameter to 500M and killed & restarted apps but no difference.

I must mention I am using pm2 for the first time. So did I configure pm2 wrong or am I missing something here? pm2 error logs are empty.

Nginx error log shows the following:

> 2016/08/12 08:39:56 [error] 7792#0: *23 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: xxx, server: xxx, request: "POST /parse/classes/AccountingDrawer HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:1337/parse/classes/AccountingDrawer", host: "xxx", referrer: "https://xxx/dashboard/apps/myapp/browser/_Role"

Nginx default config

```
server {
    listen 443;
    server_name xxx;

    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.html index.htm;

    # log files
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/parse.access.log;
    error_log   /var/log/nginx/parse.error.log;

    ssl on;
    # Use certificate and key provided by Let's Encrypt:
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/xxx/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/xxx/privkey.pem;
    ssl_session_timeout 5m;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_ciphers 'EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH';

    # Diffie-Hellman parameter for DHE ciphersuites, recommended 2048 bits
    ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/ssl/dhparam.pem;

    # Pass requests for /parse/ to Parse Server instance at localhost:1337
    location /parse/ {
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
            proxy_pass http://localhost:1337/parse/;
            proxy_ssl_session_reuse off;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_redirect off;
    }

    # Pass requests for /dashboard/ to Parse Dashboard instance at localhost:4040
    location /dashboard/ {
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
            proxy_pass http://localhost:4040/dashboard/;
            proxy_ssl_session_reuse off;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_redirect off;
    }

    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
}
```

pm2 ecosystem.json

```
{
  "apps" : [{
    "name"        : "parse-server-wrapper",
    "script"      : "/usr/bin/parse-server",
    "watch"       : true,
    "merge_logs"  : true,
    "cwd"         : "/home/parse",
    "env": {
      ...
    },
    "max_memory_restart": "500M",
    "instances"        :  2,
    "exec_interpreter" : "node",
    "exec_mode"        : "cluster"
  },
  {
    "name"        : "parse-dashboard-wrapper",
    "script"      : "/usr/bin/parse-dashboard",
    "watch"       : true,
    "merge_logs"  : true,
    "cwd"         : "/home/parse",
    "max_memory_restart": "500M",
    "env": {
      "HOST": "localhost",
      "PORT": "4040",
      "MOUNT_PATH": "/dashboard",
      "PARSE_DASHBOARD_ALLOW_INSECURE_HTTP": 1,
      ...
    }
  }]
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you could initialize the app in the command line without pm2 and run it until it crashes,  you might get more details about the crash in the terminal

Comment: I was able to get it running without the wrapper - the wrapper has problems